# query to get season specific data plus neutral objects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create query which delivers id of `Childerens` the important thing is we have season specific Childrens and neutral on. The `Childrens` table has a field named `season` which may have a value of 0,1 or 2

```
0 means Neutral / Season independet
1 means only for Summer
2 means only for Winter
```

Then it has 4 next fields `summer_from`, `summer_till`, `winter_from` and `winter_till`

I need to get all the Child object which have either season = 0 plus winter or summer specific object.

Here is my sample query which I am generating dynamically using scripting language. I have removed the script code as much as possible.

Is there a better way to write this query?

```
SELECT id
FROM Childrens
WHERE id_parent= 2656
## if the parameter 'season' is 1 or 2 then we will access
if(season == 1)
  AND Now() >= summer_from
  AND Now() <= summer_till
elseif ( season == 2 )
  AND Now() >= winter_from
  AND Now() <= winter_till


UNION 

SELECT id
FROM Childrens
WHERE id_parent= 2656
AND season = 0
AND ( 
     ( NOW() >= summer_from AND  NOW() <= summer_till) 
     OR
    ( NOW() >= winter_from AND  NOW() <= winter_till)
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your query, this is what I see:

You want to have one of the following conditions be true:

- Season = 0 and in the summer season
- Season = 1 and in the summer season
- Season = 0 and in the winter season
- Season = 2 and in the winter season.

This can be shortened to two options:

- Season != 2 and in the summer season
- Season != 1 and in the winter season

So, this is how I would write that query:

```
SELECT id
FROM Childrens
WHERE id_parent = 2656
    AND ( ((season != 1) AND (Now() >= winter_from) AND (Now() <= winter_till))
       OR ((season != 2) AND (Now() >= summer_from) AND (Now() <= summer_till)) )
```